# Flutter didReceiveRemoteNotification Not called

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-plugin

I've created a plugin which supoort Push Notification but `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` not fired
The notification is received in the following cases only:

- Call it like this `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:`
- Set `content_available` to true in the notification payload

I'm just wondering why this is happening, can anyone help me to figure out how can I make it work with `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:`?

Comment: Do you already receive the notification when `content_available` is true/ `1`? If so, there is no problem, this is the expected behaviour.

Comment: It seems that's an issue in flutter, I added this issue on GitHub you can find it here:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/52895

Answer (score 0):

Do you use FlutterAppDelegate as superclass of AppDelegte?
In FlutterAppDelegate.mm, it replaced method `respondsToSelector` like below

```
- (BOOL)respondsToSelector:(SEL)selector {
  if ([_lifeCycleDelegate isSelectorAddedDynamically:selector]) {
    return [self delegateRespondsSelectorToPlugins:selector];
  }
  return [super respondsToSelector:selector];
}
```

And there is implementation of in `FlutterPluginAppLifeCycleDelegate`

```
static const SEL selectorsHandledByPlugins[] = {
    @selector(application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:),
    @selector(application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:)};


- (BOOL)isSelectorAddedDynamically:(SEL)selector {
  for (const SEL& aSelector : selectorsHandledByPlugins) {
    if (selector == aSelector) {
      return YES;
    }
  }
  return NO;
}
```

So for calling of `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` it will call selctor in `FlutterPluginAppLifeCycleDelegate`

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application
    didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)userInfo
          fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))completionHandler {
  for (NSObject<FlutterApplicationLifeCycleDelegate>* delegate in _delegates) {
    if (!delegate) {
      continue;
    }
    if ([delegate respondsToSelector:_cmd]) {
      if ([delegate application:application
              didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo
                    fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler]) {
        return;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Maybe some plugins break the chain of calls.
It's my guess base Flutter Engine source code and I do not confirm it in a debug build of flutter engine.